# Firebase check email exist (fetchProvidersForEmail alternative)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

the fetchProvidersForEmail method is deprecated.
But on the firebase site i dont find an alternative, so i have to ask you. Hope you can help.

I want to Check if email is not already in the database, here is the old code for that.

```
  Auth.fetchProvidersForEmail(Email.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ProviderQueryResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ProviderQueryResult> task) {
```

Comment: where are you running this code? I'd like to run this for my iOS app, but having no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the documentation for `fetchProvidersForEmail` says:

> `fetchProvidersForEmail(String email)`
>
> This method was deprecated. This method is being renamed for functional clarity - please use the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(String)` method instead.

If no account exists for the email, the `SignInMethodQueryResult. getSignInMethods()` will return an empty list.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen For an user with Google or Facebook as a provider, the result returns an empty list. How do we check for an account that exists with Google or Facebook as their providers?